nicematrix \midrule undefined
Why am I getting error that \midrule is undefined?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
a & b\\
\midrule
c & d
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}

From log file:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.9.24)  28 SEP 2024 10:34
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**array.tex
(./array.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-09-10>
....
....
\c__nicematrix_shift_Ldots_last_row_dim=\dimen293
\c__nicematrix_shift_exterior_Vdots_dim=\dimen294
\c__nicematrix_innersep_middle_dim=\dimen295
\g__nicematrix_max_cell_width_dim=\dimen296
\c@iRow=\count328
\c@jCol=\count329
\l__nicematrix_cell_box=\box65
\l__nicematrix_the_array_box=\box66
\l__nicematrix_left_delim_dim=\dimen297
\l__nicematrix_right_delim_dim=\dimen298

./array.tex:7: Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \midrule
            
? 
\g__nicematrix_ddots_int=\count330
\g__nicematrix_iddots_int=\count331
\g__nicematrix_delta_x_one_dim=\dimen299
\g__nicematrix_delta_y_one_dim=\dimen300
\g__nicematrix_delta_x_two_dim=\dimen301
\g__nicematrix_delta_y_two_dim=\dimen302
\l__nicematrix_initial_i_int=\count332
\l__nicematrix_initial_j_int=\count333
\l__nicematrix_final_i_int=\count334
\l__nicematrix_final_j_int=\count335


[1

{/Users/me/Library/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.ma
p}] (./array.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-09-10>


\midrule is defined by booktabs and nicematrix doesn't load it by default.

The nicematrix documentation says "However, it’s also possible to use the tools of booktabs[5]: \toprule, \bottomrule, \midrule, etc."  Footnote [5] says "The extension booktabs is not loaded by nicematrix."
So you need to \usepackage{booktabs}.
